# Swapped graphics card, ended with dead system

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, grub2, nouveau

Where to start.... My OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 AMD64 (no specific reason to get server other than avoiding any preset desktop environment right out of the box).

I was having the fun of my lifetime with my switch from Windows to Ubuntu thanks to a NAS issue, scanner not working etc etc when I swapped graphics card with a friend (switched from GTX560ti to GTX 550ti. This is temporary) and the OS stopped booting. The graphics driver is nouveau and the boot usually stops after detecting keyboard so I suspected that driver. I chrooted into the system, but couldn't find any way to reinstall, reconfigure or even remove old config of nouveau. I could not find any standard way to debug boot issues other than a suggested ssh hack that . Before I was able to attempt that, the system somehow became even more damaged and now boot stops right at grub. I can see no grub menu, nothing. Repairing grub did not help.

If nothing else works, I am switching over to 12.10 Desktop and purging gnome post-install because that OS has got a repair install option if I heard right?

Update: I have fixed grub, but Ubuntu is still getting stuck during boot.

Comment: I have found out that the hard drive had developed many (160) bad sectors. For some reason, Windows still manages to run on it (from XP to 10), but any Ubuntu installation keeps getting corrupted. I am now running a new Ubuntu installation on the same machine but with a new hard drive. Hopefully this time everything will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If gdm is not showing login or anything to you, can you switch to text console with

`CTRL+ALT+F1` when booted